# which is better? adding a parameter or using a member function

Tags: c++, parameters, member-functions

```
void recursiveFunction(container_t container) {
    size_t max   = container.size();
    ...
}
```

This is my first implementation.

```
void recursiveFunction(container_t container, const size_t max) {
    ...
}
```

This is my second implementation.

These functions are recursive functions, so call size() function many times or have to add a parameter. but, I don't want to use global variable.
what should i do?

```
ostream& printAnswer(ostream& os, const completeTree_t& completeTree, size_t index) {
    size_t left  = index * 2;
    size_t right = index * 2 + 1;
    size_t max   = completeTree.size();
    if( left  < max )
        printAnswer(os, completeTree, left);
    os << completeTree[index];
    if( right < max )
        printAnswer(os, completeTree, right);
    return os;
}
```

This is my full source code.

Comment: That really depends on your `size` implementation. Is it expensive and does a lot of calculations (or recursions) itself? Then call it once and use a second helper function which takes the size as an argument. Otherwise no need to bother.

Comment: I would say it depends on the complexity of your `size()` function. If the function just returns the value of a member variable, then there is no problem in calling it multiple times. If the function is complex, i.e. has to count the number of elements, then it would make sense to call it once and pass the value as parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`size` on a C++ standard library container is O(1). If yours is too, then don't pass it as a parameter.

If `size` is not O(1) in your container, than my suggestion would be that you rename the method, as it will trip up future developers of your code. *Then* pass the size explicitly as a parameter if profiling your code shows it to be a bottleneck.